# what its mean by class, object, instance, attribute in object oriented programing ?

Tags: class, oop, object, attributes, instance

i have learned class is a blueprint of structurally identical items, and the items created using class are called instances.
please let me know what are the difference between class, object, instance and attribute in object oriented programming concept. is the object, instance, attribute same?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically they are used like so:

- class - blueprint for creating object instances; defines properties and methods
- object - synonymous with instance usually (sometimes improperly equated with class)
- instance - an actual manifestation of a class; the class defines what properties and methods the instance has while the instance holds the values of the object attributes
- attribute - typically synonymous with "property" (an object member whose value can be set), but in some dynamic languages this can also include "methods" (an object member which can be called)

Comment: So how can i differentiate class, object  and attribute ?

Comment: Can you please name a language where `class` is synonymous with `object`?  No language I can think of equates the two.

Comment: tanks! i'm studying these things with the subject of "object oriented analysis and  design" and i'm using C++ for this

Comment: "Object = Class" isn't a language-related thing, but an issue of imprecise language.  Developers speaking about code often times use Object to mean either Class or Instance, such as when describing prototypes.

Comment: An object is an instance of a class. A class has attributes for example 'firstname'. When you create an instance of a class (an object) you can assign data to the particular instance. So you have multiple instances of a class (objects) which can store different information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're definition of a class is correct. You can create multiple objects of the same class. Each object is an instance of the class. The term instance can not only mean the object is an instance of the class, but it can also relate to polymorphism. There is a keyword, in java it is called instanceof. With it, you can not only tell if an object is an instance of the class, but if the object is an instance of a superclass. So, instance, can also be more type-oriented. Attributes are members of the class, like its variables.