# Am I right on Object vs Instance?

Tags: php, oop

PHP class:

```
class Khmer
{
    function foo()
    {
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo '$this is defined (';
            echo get_class($this);
            echo ")<br />";
        } else {
            echo "\$this is not defined.<br />";
        }
    }
    function Me()
    {
            echo "Cambodia.<br />";
    }
};

/******************/
$a = new Khmer();
$a->me();

/******************/
```

I think that `$a` is an object and `$a->me()` is an instance.
Am I right?

Comment: $a is an instance of the  class khmer

Comment: thank for comment. I checked many web site about it but pretty note sure.
so could you give me an example about object and instance, Dagon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what its mean by class, object, instance, attribute in object oriented programing ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744847/what-its-mean-by-class-object-instance-attribute-in-object-oriented-programin)

Comment: :) Pleasure. Does everyone dare to say Object and Instance are exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are instances, instances are objects.

The difference is that the term **instance** only works with the preposition **of**.

> Object `$a` is an instance **of** class `Khmer` (*or:* a `Khmer` instance)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

The most commonly used definition for an object is:

> An object is an instance of a classGood mornin.

`$a` is an object(which itself is actually an instance of the class `khmer`). `$a->me();` is a call to a member function `me()` with respect to the object `$a`.